# how to react-Native deep link to open native camera app?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to open the native camera app from a react-native app but it doesn't have any connection to the react-native app. it should run separately if triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-Native do not give inbuilt support for camera module. You might like to use [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) module for this. It is the most popular and highly customisable library for using camera module in React-Native.

Comment: but react-native-camera runs the camera app over the react-native app, is there a module to just independently open an existing camera app ?

Comment: No there are no such modules to independently open an existing camera app. React-Native Linking module is used for opening deep links but I do not think that it is possible for your use case.